# getting this error in codeigniter, Error Number: 1096 No tables used SELECT *

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this Error Number: 1096  No tables used  SELECT * ,my code is below not getting  what is wrong in that

```
public function product_approve($id) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('approve_products');
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query= $this->db->get();

            if ( $this->db->get()->num_rows() > 0 )
        {

                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $this->db->insert('sub3_category',$row);
                                                   }
               // $this->db->insert('sub3_category',$query);

                if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0){
                    $this->db->where('id', $id);
                    $this->db->delete('approve_products');
                }
        }



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line of your code

```
if ( $this->db->get()->num_rows() > 0 )
```

with

```
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$query= $this->db->get();
if ( $this->db->get()->num_rows() > 0 )
```

Into

```
$query= $this->db->get('approve_products');
if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
```

And also remove/comment the following line.

```
$this->db->from('approve_products');
```

[Ref](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html#query-builder-query)

You can use `$this->db->from('approve_products')` too but not `$this->db->from('approve_products')` and `$this->db->get('approve_products')` both at same.

Comment: i think you can use $this->db->from('approve_products');. in active record this is valid. check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: @Rahul what is error?
I have update my answer again.

Answer (score -2):

```
private function _get_datatables_queryarc($id,$table)
    {
        if ($id==1){
            $this->db->select('`id`,`name`,`gov`,`proince`');
            $this->db->from($table);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When a question has several answers, as well as an accepted answer, it would be best to provide users of the site with some explanation as to why your response is unique or better than what's already been provided.

Comment: I've fixed the format, but I leave to you further details and the missing bracket.